# Move BindingResult check from Controller to Aspect or Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple multiple methods in my `Controller` and each one has a `ModelAttribute` with a `BindingResult` such as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somewhere", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SomeDTO someMethod(@Valid SomeModel someModel, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("some error", bindingResult);
    }

    SomeDTO someDTO = someService.doSomething(someModel);

    return someDTO;
}
```

I'd like to DRY up my code a bit and put the `BindingResult` check in something like an `Aspect` or `Interceptor.` In other words, I don't want to do the following check in every method:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    throw new InvalidRequestException("some error", bindingResult);
}
```

Anytime a method is called on a `@Controller` I want to check the `BindingResult` and if there is an error, then throw my custom `InvalidRequestException`. That way my Controllers don't need to do a check.

My initial thought was to have an aspect that checks for this:

pseudocode

```
@Before("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller)")
public void myMethod( JoinPoint jp ) throws Throwable {

    Signature signature = jp.getSignature();
    Object [] args = jp.getArgs();

    for(Object arg : args){
        if(arg instanceof BindingResult){
            BindingResult br = (BindingResult) arg;
            if(br.hasErrors()){
                throw new InvalidRequestException("Error...", br);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this would be a good way to handle this or not. Is there an easier way to do this? Or something in Spring that can help do this?

The reasoning behind this is that I have a form that submits two different `ModelAttributes`. So every method has two `BindingResults` which makes the checking a bit larger and I actually do something like the following:

```
if (br1.hasErrors() || br2.hasErrors()) {
    List<Errors> errors = new ArrayList<Errors>();

    if(br1.hasErrors()){
        errors.add(br1);
    }

    if(br2.hasErrors()){
        errors.add(br2);
    }

    throw new InvalidRequestException("Error...", errors.toArray(new Errors[errors.size()]));
}
```

So not having to do this check in every method would be nice.

Comment: your approach of doing this piece of login in Aspect is right. But there is a small glitch. I don't think Spring validation would have kicked in by the time the control reaches your aspect. So BindingResult, will not have anything.

Comment: If you dont have bindingresult as a parameter spring will automatically throw a bindingexception if I'm not mistaken. As long as you dont do anything specific with the bindingresult this could be handled with an errorhandler in a global advice.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, yet an answer would have spared me a lot of time. Therefore:

In my Controller I have the `@Valid` annotation, the `BindingResult` is not necessary here:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> webHook(@Valid @RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO) {
    ...
}
```

And then I use a `@ControllerAdvice` to handle the error:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DtoValidationAdvice{

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
}
```